# Space sci-fi Book with character Sam, oral sex, "frothy", he dies

Tags: story-identification, novel

Checked out of middle school library, I recall the librarian telling me it had some adult themes.  Read it sometime between 93 and 97. Same time as I read Crystal Singer.

Some kind of space future sci-fi novel.

All I remember is the following scene:
a character Sam who has oral sex with female protagonist, describes it as frothy or something, later asked to stop during intercourse like "Sam, wait", comes anyway, receives apology from woman, and then dies in next scene while doing some kind of space repair.

I may have it all wrong. Looking back 20 years, wondering how it was available to my middle school mind.  Not sure if sex would be in a young adult book ...

Any help with the title?

Comment: Probably wasn't a young adult book - some libraries dont get enough books to be picky, and some librarians filter the reader not the book, which it sounds like yours tried to. Not ringing any bells offhand, although it sounds like the same vein as *Crystal Singer*.

Comment: Possibly 'Space for Hire', the first of a series of SF books about a detective named Sam Space written by William F Nolan in 1971. Nolan is more famous for writing 'Logan's Run'. His stuff tends to have more sex than usual in mainstream SF.